# Passing a function pointer by reference

Tags: c++

Hi I am trying to learn some function pointers in C/C++ and I was trying to write the following C++ code with gcc on Ubuntu.

This code should execute the multiply or or the add function depending on the 
preprocessor flag -DADD or -DMULTIPLY provided during compilation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
//Adds two numbers
int add(int a, int b)
{
  return a+b;
}
//Multiplies two numbers
int multiply(int a, int b)
{
  return a*b;
}

//Function to set the correct function to be executed.
//All functions here should have the same signature.
void functionsetter( void (*ptr2fun)(int,int)  )
{
#ifdef ADD
  ptr2fun   = add;
#endif

#ifdef MULTIPLY 
   ptr2fun  = multiply
#endif
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int a = 5;
  int b = 6;

  void (*foo)(int,int);
  functionsetter(foo);

   return 0;
}
```

I cannot figure out how to pass the function pointer `foo` to the `function-setter` function by reference. Can someone help me out on this.I am sure the declaration of

`functionsetter` is wrong in the code, Please let me know how to fix it.

I am trying to compile this with `g++ -O2 -g -Wall  -DADD main.cpp -o main`

Note: I want to use such preprocessor flags and function pointers in some other-code elsewhere. 
Please let me know if such a thing is a good idea / practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `typedef`:

```
typedef void (*MyFunctionPointer)(int,int);
void functionsetter(MyFunctionPointer& fp);
```

---

> I want to use such preprocessor flags and function pointers in some other-code elsewhere. Please let me know if such a thing is a good idea / practice.

No, not really.  It isn't clear from your example what you are trying to accomplish, but your implementation is rather unusual.  Consider using virtual member functions or `std::function` to switch function implementations at runtime, or (possibly) templates to switch them at compile-time.  There's nothing wrong with using conditional compilation for static selection like this, but mixing that with function pointers is a bit odd.

Without a good understanding of the problem you are trying to solve, it's difficult to give good advice as to how best to solve it.

Answer (score 14):

Without using a `typedef`, the syntax for a reference to a function pointer is:

```
void functionsetter(void (*&ptr2fun)(int, int)) { ... }
```

But it is generally simpler to create a `typedef` for the pointer type:

```
typedef void (*FunctionPointer)(int, int);

void functionsetter(FunctionPointer& ptr2fun) { ... }
```

Or for the function type:

```
typedef void Function(int, int);

void functionsetter(Function*& ptr2fun) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd change your signature to:

```
void functionsetter( void (*&ptr2fun)(int,int)  )
```

Note that the ptr2fun function pointer has the wrong signature, your add and multiply functions return an int, and so should `ptr2fun`

This becomes a lot easier if you use a typedef:

```
typedef int (*ptr2fun)(int,int);
void functionsetter(ptr2fun& func) { ...
```

Though, personally I'd just return the function pointer.

```
ptr2fun functionsetter()
{
#ifdef ADD
  return add;
#endif

#ifdef MULTIPLY 
   return multiply
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you're not passing a function pointer *reference* to the method, you're just passing a function pointer. You need to change the method signature to

```
void functionsetter( void (*&ptr2fun)(int,int)  )
```

Also, your method signature is `void(*)(int,int)` in some places and `int(*)(int,int)` in some, they should probably be the latter everywhere since your add and multiply methods return `int`.

That said, since you're using C++, manipulating pointers in this manner isn't something I'd recommend, C++ has inheritance/virtual methods that can usually replace most function pointer use and makes the code much more readable and extensible.